# Version conflict when deploying translations including FlowDefinition tags v44.0 & above

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api

Since API Version 44.0 Salesforce has updated the wayflow deployment should be handled:

In API version 44.0, we recommend upgrading your flows to flow metadata file names without version numbers and discontinue using the FlowDefinition object to activate or deactivate a flow. Then use the Flow object to activate or deactivate a flow. For more information, see Upgrade Flow Files to API Version 44.0.

This in my feeling is a major improvement, however we are still struggling with the version number of the FlowDefinition in our **translations** metadata. E.g.:

sample out a translations .xml file:

> ```
> <flowDefinitions>
>     <flows>
>         <fullName>Product_Edit-13</fullName>
>     </flows>
>     <fullName>Product_Edit</fullName>
> </flowDefinitions>
> ```

The translations.xml file still contains the versionNumber and the **FlowDefinition** tag.
This means that if you have done multiple clones of your flow, the deployment will always fail because it will not find the version of flow that is mentioned in the translations .xml file.

Did Salesforce really introduce this flow version fix just to introduce another problem with the translations? Or am I missing something crucial here ?

Answer (score 2):

Per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_translations.htm) it also allows the translations without a version specification. It assumes the latest version in that case.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, it does require you to remove the version number manually from the translation file.